# Get list of feusers with typoscript, can't get the names of the associated usergroups

Tags: select, typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I am generating this list of feusers and trying to get the names of the associated usergroups. This code worked **before the update** to TYPO3 8.x (it's just the relevant part of the whole thing):

```
    40 = TEXT
40.field = usergroup
40.split {
    token = ,
    cObjNum = 1 || 2
    1 {
      10 = CONTENT
      10.table = fe_groups       
      10.select.pidInList = 22 
      10.select.andWhere.current = 1
      10.select.andWhere.wrap = uid=|
      10.select.where = (title NOT LIKE 'Netzwerk')
      10.renderObj = TEXT
      10.renderObj.field = title
      10.renderObj.wrap = |,&nbsp;<br />
            }
       2 < .1
       2.10.renderObj.wrap >
      }
```

With TYPO3 8 the 'andWhere' is depreciated and so I tried like this, but failed:

```
     40 = TEXT
     40.field = usergroup 
     40.split {
         token = ,
         cObjNum = 1 || 2
         1{
             10 = CONTENT
             10 {
                 table = fe_groups
                 select {
                     pidInList = 22
                     where.current = 1
                     where.wrap = uid= |
                 }
                10.renderObj = TEXT 
                10.renderObj.field = title
                10.renderObj.wrap = |,&nbsp;
             }
            2 < .1
            2.10.renderObj.wrap
            }
        }
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should not split up the comma separated values, but go for uidInList instead. This way you get rid of the surrounding split and fetch the elements within just one go.

```
40 = CONTENT
40 {
    table = fe_groups
    select {
        uidInList.field = usergroup
        pidInList = 22
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj.field = title
    renderObj.wrap = |,&nbsp;
}
```